# How to add executable binaries to Xcode4 project

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode4

I have some binaries (executables plus some dynamic libraries) which I want to include as part of the application bundle. How do I go about adding those to xcode such as they are all properly signed when archived?

Comment: iOS or OS X? You can't do this for iOS.

Comment: I am interested in OS X only.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your binaries wherever you want in your bundle. Just create a "Copy files" build phase in your target. And than you must sign this binaries separately, **before** signing the main bundle.
You can also create the "Run script" phase and sign your binaries inside this phase.

```
codesign -s "authority" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/path/to/your/lib.dylib"
```

Comment: How about adding the binaries as a framework? What if I create a framework called Acme.framework and just put the binaries in there? Than I can import it like a standard framework.

Comment: Yes, it'll be the best way. But you also have to sign your framework as a separate bundle.